# Detect Android phone via Javascript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, android

How would i detect that the device in use is an Android for a mobile website?

I need to apply certain css attributes to the Android platform.

Thanks

Answer (score 247, accepted):

Take a look at that : http://davidwalsh.name/detect-android

JavaScript:

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1; //&& ua.indexOf("mobile");
if(isAndroid) {
  // Do something!
  // Redirect to Android-site?
  window.location = 'http://android.davidwalsh.name';
}
```

PHP:

```
$ua = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
if(stripos($ua,'android') !== false) { // && stripos($ua,'mobile') !== false) {
  header('Location: http://android.davidwalsh.name');
  exit();
}
```

---

**Edit** : As pointed out in some comments, this will work in 99% of the cases, but some edge cases are not covered. If you need a much more advanced and bulletproofed solution in JS, you should use platform.js : https://github.com/bestiejs/platform.js

Comment: don't forget to also check for android tablets: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/03/mo-better-to-also-detect-mobile-user.html

Comment: It's worth noting that this does not always work for android devices as, for example, the user agents which are reported by Kindle Fire HD devices do not contain the word 'android' at all.

Comment: Different versions of Android have different features, how about adding version detection? Useful when segmenting Gingerbread from Jelly Bean. The older doesnt support positon: fixed, just for example. So, things like backstretch won't work on Gingerbread. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184573/pick-up-the-android-version-in-the-browser-by-javascript

Comment: The navigator.userAgent approach doesnt work on samsung galaxy devices. There's no 'Android' in the browser spec.

Comment: The first two lines of the JS solution can be simplified to: `var isAndroid = /Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent)`

Comment: Your solution doesn't work. Here is a Nokia Lumia user agent. And Guess what? it matches as android :
`Mozilla/5.0 (Mobile; Windows Phone 8.1; Android 4.0; ARM; Trident/7.0; Touch; rv:11.0; IEMobile/11.0; NOKIA; Lumia 625; Orange) like iPhone OS 7_0_3 Mac OS X AppleWebKit/537 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile Safari/537`

Comment: Your solution wrongly reports a Pinephone under Mobian Linux as an Android device.

Answer (score 60):

How about this one-liner?

```
var isAndroid = /(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
```

The `i` modifier is used to perform case-insensitive matching.

---

Technique taken from Cordova AdMob test project: https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro/wiki/00.-How-To-Use-with-PhoneGap-Build

Comment: The parentheses can be omitted here since you don't need to "capture" the result, so it just becomes: `/android/i`

Answer (score 3):

I think Michal's answer is the best, but we can take it a step further and dynamically load an Android CSS as per the original question:

```
var isAndroid = /(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
if (isAndroid) {
    var css = document.createElement("link");
    css.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
    css.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
    css.setAttribute("href", "/css/android.css");
    document.body.appendChild(css);
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that, while you can use media queries? JS device detection should be only for enhancement, like adding an invitation to install your app. The page rendering never should rely on it because you will have performance issues and a horrible usability experience.

Comment: @camilokawerin Your response should be directed to the author. I was simply providing an answer to his question. There are cases though where you'd like platform specific CSS. For example, if you want the visual style of the interface to match the device.

Answer (score 2):

```
;(function() {
    var redirect = false
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) {
        redirect = true
    }
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) {
        redirect = true
    }
    var isAndroid = /(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent)
    var isMobile = /(mobile)/i.test(navigator.userAgent)
    if (isAndroid && isMobile) {
        redirect = true
    }
    if (redirect) {
        window.location.replace('jQueryMobileSite')
    }
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option for the css part, you can do:

```
document.documentElement.className += ((/(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ? " android" : " notAndroid");
```

And then use simple css selectors like:

```
html.android .mainMenu {
  width: 100%;
}

html.notAndroid .mainMenu {
  width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

js version, catches iPad too:

```
var is_mobile = /mobile|android/i.test (navigator.userAgent);
```

Comment: Doesn't work because it catches many devices, not just Android as the question requires.

Comment: Use at least something like this: /android.*(?=mobile)/i.test(navigator.userAgent); to detect Android phone. But this regex contains "expensive" quantifiers, so Philip's answer with 2 separate tests may be more appropriate.