# Get Android Mobile Version with HTML/JS and change CSS style depending if low or high version

Tags: javascript, android, css

I'am fixing a site so it will look good on Android (only), and I'am using **position:fixed** which is not supported in **2.1-update1** for an example but it works fine when I test on **2.2.1**.

I would like to know if I can get to know what android version the user uses and then depending on what version they have the navigator(which has the **position:fixed**) can changes style to something else that looks good on **2.1-update1** and maybe lower but that **2.2.1** still using the one with **position:fixed**.

Can only use Javascript and HTML, no php.

Here is a version of the site:
http://heeej.mooo.com/app/index_2.html

I would be very grateful if I could get any answer or other options to my problem.

Edit:
I now found this:
[Pick up the Android version in the browser by Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184573/pick-up-the-android-version-in-the-browser-by-javascript)

And an example:
alert(window.navigator.userAgent)
// alerts "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Win98; en-US; rv:0.9.2) Gecko/20010725 Netscape6/6.1"

The example worked good on the phones I tested on. Can I now somehow use this function and do an 'if' the function contain "android 2.1-update1" 'this' happen(change css) 'else' nothing.

Comment: Yes you can do if condition based on version number