# How to detect Android's version number in Firefox for Android?

Tags: javascript, android, firefox, user-agent, detection

For a website we want to show a link in the play store if the user comes with an Android 4+ device. All browsers we tested sent the version number of Android in their user-agent string, except one: Firefox for Android. Firefox just sends this:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Android; Mobile; rv:19.0) Gecko/19.0 Firefox/19.0
```

and even with some JavaScript I can't find any evidence for the version number:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
  document.write(navigator.appVersion + "\n<br/>OS CPU: " + navigator.oscpu);
</script>
```

returns:

```
5.0 (Android)
OS CPU: Linux arm7l
```

Did I miss some other methods?

Comment: **See**: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184573/pick-up-the-android-version-in-the-browser-by-javascript

Comment: navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Android') should return the version

Comment: I didn't test that, but if this is true, you can report to mozilla. However, I don't think it is very wise to show different page to different version of Android platform.

Comment: First two posters: That's the point, firefox does not report the version in the user agent. So your solution does not work.

@JermaineXu In this case it makes sense, since the app on the play store has Android 4 as its requirement.

Comment: I understand that, but I think a warning is enough. You can show the link to all the users and tell them Android 4 required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot. See [Bug 625238 - Add device info to User-Agent](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=625238) and the related [Bug 807495 - User Agent does not include handset Device Model](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=807495).

In general, Mozilla has a policy of not adding User Agent (or HTTP header) information, and they currently have the opinion that developers do not need to know the running Android version.