# How to detect whether browser is iOS, android or desktop using jquery?

Tags: android, jquery, ios, desktop, browser-detection

The idea is to make a button that says "get app now" with a link that changes based on whether its an android phone iPhone or none. I looked through stackexchange for answers but nothing is clear for someone who has no js experience

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

Unknown is desktop or any other phone

```
function getMobileOperatingSystem() {
  var userAgent = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;

  if( userAgent.match( /iPad/i ) || userAgent.match( /iPhone/i ) || userAgent.match( /iPod/i ) )
  {
    return 'iOS';

  }
  else if( userAgent.match( /Android/i ) )
  {

    return 'Android';
  }
  else
  {
    return 'unknown'; 
  }
}
```

Source: [Detecting iOS / Android Operating system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21741841/detecting-ios-android-operating-system)

Answer (score 1):

//TO check device is mobile or desktop.

```
if(jQuery.browser.mobile)
{
   console.log('You are using a mobile device!');
}
else
{
   console.log('You are not using a mobile device!');
}
```

//Detect iPad

```
var isiPad = /ipad/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());
if (isiPad)
{
  ...
}
```

//Detect iPhone

```
var isiPhone = /iphone/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());
if (isiPhone)
{
  ...
}
```

//Detect iPod

```
var isiPod = /ipod/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());
if (isiPod)
{
  ...
}
```

//Detect iDevice

```
var isiDevice = /ipad|iphone|ipod/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());

if (isiDevice)
{
  ...
}
```

//Detect Andriod

```
var isAndroid = /android/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());

if (isAndroid)
{
  ...
}
```

//Detect Blackberry

```
var isBlackBerry = /blackberry/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());

if (isBlackBerry)
{
  ...
}
```

//Detect WebOs

```
var isWebOS = /webos/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());

if (isWebOS)
{
  ...
}
```

//Detect Windows Phone

```
var isWindowsPhone = /windows phone/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());
if (isWindowsPhone)
{
  ...
}
```

The mentioned code is what I found at the following link.
https://www.sitepoint.com/detect-mobile-devices-jquery/

Answer (score 1):

The answer from [Tom Landau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2941060/tom-landau) in js <= ES5 (using "old" language grammar):

```
/**
 * @summary
 * utils.isMobile
 * --------------
 * @desc
 * Creates a global object with member functions that test if the client's browser 
 * belongs to a specific family of devices.
 * @function utils.isMobile
 * @return {Boolean}
 * @see {@link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32570067/how-to-detect-whether-browser-is-ios-android-or-desktop-using-jquery}, 
 * {@link https://bitsrc.io/tomlandau/simple-js/global/is-mobile/code#src/global/isMobile.js}
 */
utils = window.utils || {};
utils.isMobile = {
   getUserAgent: function() {
      return navigator.userAgent;
   },
   Android: function() {
      return /Android/i.test(this.getUserAgent()) && !this.Windows();
   },
   BlackBerry: function() {
      return /BlackBerry|BB10|PlayBook/i.test(this.getUserAgent());;
   },
   iPhone: function() {
      return /iPhone/i.test(this.getUserAgent()) && !this.iPad() && !this.Windows();
   },
   iPod: function() {
      return /iPod/i.test(this.getUserAgent());
   },
   iPad: function() {
      return /iPad/i.test(this.getUserAgent());
   },
   iOS: function() {
      return (this.iPad() || this.iPod() || this.iPhone());
   },
   Opera: function() {
      return /Opera Mini/i.test(this.getUserAgent());
   },
   Windows: function() {
      return /Windows Phone|IEMobile|WPDesktop/i.test(this.getUserAgent());
   },
   KindleFire: function() {
      return /Kindle Fire|Silk|KFAPWA|KFSOWI|KFJWA|KFJWI|KFAPWI|KFAPWI|KFOT|KFTT|KFTHWI|KFTHWA|KFASWI|KFTBWI|KFMEWI|KFFOWI|KFSAWA|KFSAWI|KFARWI/i.test(this.getUserAgent());
   },
   any: function() {
      return (this.Android() || this.BlackBerry() || this.iOS() || this.Opera() || this.Windows());
   }
};
```

Tested as usual: `if(utils.isMobile.any())...` or `if(utils.isMobile.Android())...`.