# How to know site open in mobile or PC browser?

Tags: php, menu, responsive-design, cross-browser

I am developing site in `php with responsive HTML`. Now, I want to hide menu if user open that site in `mobile browser (iOS and Android)`.

Then how i can verify in `HTML or jQuery` so i can `hide menu.` I tried to find but not get any proper solution.

Let me know if any one have.

Thanks

Comment: You can do that a lot better with CSS Media-Queries than with PHP.

Comment: Thanks but can you give me. I am not a designer so.

Comment: Neither am I, but media queries aren't difficult to learn. There are enough tutorials and documentations in the web which you can check out. SO is not a site where other to work for you, it's a site where others help you do your work.

Comment: But i want to know that site open in which platform devices? ios or android? How?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

with **CSS** you can use @media-queries like the following:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1199px) {
 .your-navigation{
   display:none;
 }
}
```

or you use **jQuery** like the following:

```
if($(window).width()<=1199){
  $(".your-navigation").hide();
}
```

but i would go with media queries, because its a more elegant and more easy to change way!

so actually you are not checking if its a mobile browser or desktop, but its totally okay, to check the width of the browser... i think, thats more what you want...

** edit **

after some thoughts i just wanna say, that it is possible to get the current browser by using javascript, but i wouldn't recommend that to you, because its not rubust and you will have a lot of pain with getting all browsers and so on... as i already said, go with the width! :)

(here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400935/browser-detection-in-javascript) with an approach)

** edit 2 **

regarding your comment:

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21741841/detecting-ios-android-operating-system) link out, it should be exactly what you want

here the code, thanks to [feeela](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341201/feeela)

```
/**
 * Determine the mobile operating system.
 * This function either returns 'iOS', 'Android' or 'unknown'
 *
 * @returns {String}
 */
function getMobileOperatingSystem() {
  var userAgent = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;

  if( userAgent.match( /iPad/i ) || userAgent.match( /iPhone/i ) || userAgent.match( /iPod/i ) )
  {
    return 'iOS';

  }
  else if( userAgent.match( /Android/i ) )
  {

    return 'Android';
  }
  else
  {
    return 'unknown';
  }
}
```

Comment: Good one but i want to know that site open in which platform devices? ios or android? How?

Comment: i've edited  my post, hope that gives you what you want (accepted answer from the link)