# How to make a link redirecting on Apple store or Google play

Tags: android, ios, redirect, deep-linking

We have an app which is compatible for desktop, Apple user and Android user, it opens in our website via a linked button, is it possibile to redirect to the correct app store or maybe even open the correct app if the user is on mobile?

Comment: your question is website source related that refer this link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21741841/detecting-ios-android-operating-system

Comment: This is definitely possible, but it's a pretty involved system to implement. You might take a look at a service like [Branch.io](https://branch.io) or [Yozio](http://www.yozio.com) for it, since there are quite a few edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

On Android, to have a link in your web page be opened with your app, you would enable deep linking by puting an intent filter with action `VIEW` on the activity in the manifest file.  The filter has a `data` attribute that specifies the URL to link from.

You can read all the details here: [Enabling Deep Links for App Content | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html)

You can offer a link to your Play Store listing using the `market:` URL scheme.  For example, you can check if your user-agent request header contains "android" and if it does, display a link like this:

```
    <a href="market://details?id=com.your.package.name">Get our app on Google Play Store</a>
```

The Android browser recognizes the `market:` scheme and opens the Play Store app on your app's page.  You can read about this here: [Linking to Your Products | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/promote/linking.html)