# Change hover settings for different mobile browsers?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

I've got a website that utilizes :hover effects in the navbar & body.

Using the mobile version of Safari on i-devices, hover events become "double-tap" events: one tap to display what would normally appear when 'hovering', and a second tap to 'click' the link. This feature is useful for certain things... displaying a text dropdown on a thumbnail image, for instance, but annoying when selecting a navbar link.

On my android device using Chrome, the opposite occurs by default: Hover effects are simply ignored, no double click, nadda.

How might I modify the default ":hover becomes 'double-click' " behavior for specific objects on mobile versions of safari, while "adding" that functionality for android users?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the exact setup of your coding, but there are several options you have.

First of all instead of browser or OS detection it is better to use **feature detection** (if possible), because feature detection will work for every setup instead for specific browsers or OS'. There are some frameworks out there you can use like [modernizr](https://modernizr.com/).

Another way to deal with things like this is to use **CSS Hacks** that only apply if it's the specific device/browser/OS. You will find hundreds of CSS Hacks in the net.

There are other ways to detect the browser/OS like the **user agent** string, for solutions going in this direction I can recommend this question [How to detect Safari, Chrome, IE, Firefox and Opera browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser) and [Detecting iOS / Android Operating system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21741841/detecting-ios-android-operating-system).

What really fits your use case best, you have to decide yourself, but this are the options I suggest.