# Phonegap Cordova Statusbar Plugin creating double bars

Tags: javascript, ios, css, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am working on an app using phonegap.  Building through CLI, not phonegap build.  I am having an issue with the cordova-plugin-statusbar plugin.  It will add an extra bar height when turned on.   Here is what it looks like.

double height menu bar:

[image: double height menu bar]

I have implemented the status bar in two ways.  First by adding tags to config.xml

```
<platform name="ios">
    <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
    <preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="default" />
    <preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#000000" />
</platform>
```

I have also done this with javascript, (by first removing the config tags) and adding the following to my DeviceReady function

```
StatusBar.overlaysWebView( false );
StatusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#000000');
StatusBar.styleDefault();
```

To see what was going on, i have changed the color and I get this

Double status bar 2 colors:

[image: Double status bar 2 colors.]

also when I remove everything or set the overlaysWebView to 'true', I get no spacing and my content is under the menubar.

```
StatusBar.overlaysWebView( true );
```

Which leads me to believe that I do not have a CSS issue.  Also, i went through my css and do not see anything that would be adding this.  my css is pretty basic so far.

```
/* Style Reset */
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}

body {
    line-height: 1;

}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
/* End of style reset */

* {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); /* make transparent link selection, adjust last value opacity 0 to 1.0 */
}

body {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;                /* prevent callout to copy image, etc when tap to hold */
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;             /* prevent webkit from resizing text to fit */
    -webkit-user-select: none;                  /* prevent copy paste, to allow, change 'none' to 'text' */
/*    background-color:#E4E4E4;
    background-image:linear-gradient(top, #A7A7A7 0%, #E4E4E4 51%);
    background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #A7A7A7 0%, #E4E4E4 51%);
    background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #A7A7A7 0%, #E4E4E4 51%);
    background-image:-webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        left top,
        left bottom,
        color-stop(0, #A7A7A7),
        color-stop(0.51, #E4E4E4)
    );
    background-attachment:fixed;*/
    font-family:'HelveticaNeue-Light', 'HelveticaNeue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
/*    height:100%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    width:100%;*/
    background-color: #333333;
}

.md-button {
    color:#DFE5E6;
    background-color:#1D1D1D;
}

.md-button[disabled] {
  border: 1px solid black;
  color : rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  background-color: transparent;
}


/* Portrait layout (default) */
.app {
    background:url(../img/logo.png) no-repeat center top; /* 170px x 200px */
    position:absolute;             /* position in the center of the screen */
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    height:50px;                   /* text area height */
    width:225px;                   /* text area width */
    text-align:center;
    padding:180px 0px 0px 0px;     /* image height is 200px (bottom 20px are overlapped with text) */
    margin:-115px 0px 0px -112px;  /* offset vertical: half of image height and text area height */
                                   /* offset horizontal: half of text area width */
}

/* Landscape layout (with min-width) */
@media screen and (min-aspect-ratio: 1/1) and (min-width:400px) {
    .app {
        background-position:left center;
        padding:75px 0px 75px 170px;  /* padding-top + padding-bottom + text area = image height */
        margin:-90px 0px 0px -198px;  /* offset vertical: half of image height */
                                      /* offset horizontal: half of image width and text area width */
    }
}

/* Custom Fonts */
@font-face {
    font-family: "sapient_sans_regular";
    src: url("../fonts/sapient_sans_regular.TTF") format("opentype"); 
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "sapient_sans_regular_italic";
    src: url("../fonts/sapient_sans_regular_italic.TTF") format("opentype"); 
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "sapient_sans_bold";
    src: url("../fonts/sapient_sans_bold.TTF") format("opentype"); 
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "sapient_sans_bold_italic";
    src: url("../fonts/sapient_sans_bold_italic.TTF") format("opentype"); 
}


.material-icons {
    margin:0px;
    color:white; 
    height:40px; 
    width:40px; 
    line-height:40px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    background: #1D1D1D;
}
.material-icons.md-menu-item.md-icon {
    text-align: left;
}

.material-icons.menuItem {
    background: transparent;
    color:#DFE5E6; 
}

#menuBar ul {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: #1D1D1D;
}
#menuBar li {
    text-align:center;
    display: inline;
}

.logo {
    line-height:11px;
    padding:13px 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    //float:left;
    //margin: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    width:100%;
    background-color: #1D1D1D;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
.my {
    //line-height:40px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    font-family: "sapient_sans_bold";
    //display: inline-block;
    font-size:20px;
    color: #DFE5E6;
}
.company {
    //line-height:40px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    font-family: "sapient_sans_bold";
    font-size:20px;
    color: #6D6E70;
}

#menuListing ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

#menuListing li a {
    font-family:'sapient_sans_regular';
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Change the link color on hover */
#menuListing li a:hover {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}
.content {
    color: white;
    padding:10px;
}

h1 {
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:normal;
    //margin:0px;
    //overflow:visible;
    //padding:0px;
    //text-align:center;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}

#map
{

    //margin: auto;
    //width: 100%;
    border: 3px solid green;
    padding: 100px;
    //height: 90%;
    //width: 60%;
}
```

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the plugin and the ios platform with no change to the issue.

I have tested this on multiple IOS simulators (different phones) and all have the same result, I have not tested directly on a device yet, but I doubt it would be different.

I have noticed that android also has a status bar buffer (even though it should not), but it is only the single white bar.  I assume that would suggest CSS, but i do not see this in the browser when I run

> phonegap serve

Quick Update:  I am taking a break from the statusBar and working on getting my google maps plugin to also work, I made some changes and the status bar seems to be working now.  There must have been some sort of interaction.  Going to see if i could figure out what exactly.

Some HTML for reference
Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="snApp">
<head>

    <title>My Test App</title>
</head>

<!-- Actual Content -->
<body ng-cloak>

    <div ng-include="'app/menuBar/menuBar.html'"></div>
    <!-- Main content Area -->
    <md-content flex id="main">
        <ng-view></ng-view>
    </md-content>

</body>
</html>
```

MenuBar.html (note, i have made some adjustments from this original posting.  I have tried to revert them.)

```
<div ng-controller="menuBarController as menuBarController" id="menuBarContainer">

<md-toolbar id="menuBar" class="md-short" layout="row">
    <div class="menuButton">
        <md-icon ng-click="menuBarController.toggleLeftMenu();" md-font-library="material-icons">menu</md-icon>
    </div>

    <div class="logo">
        <span class="my">My</span><!-- this removes the space (for some reason) --><span class="app">App</span>
    </div>
</md-toolbar>

<md-sidenav md-component-id="left" class="md-sidenav-left" >
    <md-menu-item>
    </md-menu-item> <!-- remove this after adding in the buffer -->

    <md-menu-item>
        <md-button ng-click="menuBarController.toggleLeftMenu();" ng-href="#/"> 
            <md-icon md-font-library="material-icons" class="menuItem">home
            </md-icon> Home
        </md-button>
    </md-menu-item>

    <md-menu-item>
        <md-button ng-click="menuBarController.toggleLeftMenu();" ng-href="#/locations">
            <md-icon md-font-library="material-icons" class="menuItem">location_city
            </md-icon>Locations
        </md-button>
    </md-menu-item>

    <md-menu-item>
        <md-button ng-click="menuBarController.toggleLeftMenu();" ng-href="#/map">
            <md-icon md-font-library="material-icons" class="menuItem">map
            </md-icon>Map
        </md-button>
    </md-menu-item>

    <md-menu-item>
        <md-button ng-click="menuBarController.toggleLeftMenu();" ng-href="#/navigate">
            <md-icon md-font-library="material-icons" class="menuItem">navigation
            </md-icon>Navigate
        </md-button>
    </md-menu-item>

    <md-menu-item>
        <md-button ng-click="menuBarController.toggleLeftMenu();" ng-href="#/about">
            <md-icon md-font-library="material-icons" class="menuItem">info
            </md-icon>About
        </md-button>
    </md-menu-item>
</md-sidenav>
</div>
```

Controller for MenuBar

```
console.log("menuBar.controller.js file loaded");

snApp.controller('menuBarController', ['$mdSidenav', '$window', MenuBarController]);


function MenuBarController($mdSidenav, $window) {
    var vm = this;

    // vm.operatingSystem = $window.operatingSystem;
    vm.operatingSystem = null;
    vm.toggleLeftMenu = toggleLeftMenu;
    vm.checkForIos = checkForIos;

    function toggleLeftMenu() {
        $mdSidenav('left').toggle();
    }
}
```

View example - Home.html page is super simple right now for testing:

```
<!-- home.html -->
<div class="content" ng-controller="HomeController as home">
    <h1>Home Page</h1>
    <p>{{ home.message }}</p>
</div>
```

home.controller.js

```
console.log("home.controller.js file loaded");

angular.module('snApp')
.controller("HomeController", HomeController);

function HomeController() {
    //debugger;
    var vm = this;
    vm.message = "this is a home message";
}
```

map.html - Here is the maps view - a lot is in there just for testing right now.

```
<!-- map.html -->
<div class="content" ng-controller="MapController as map">
    <h1>Map Page</h1>
    <md-content  layout-gt-sm="row" layout-padding>
        <md-button ng-click="map.setMapToDiv();">show map</md-button>
        <md-button ng-click="map.getLocation();" ng-disabled="map.buttonDisabled">{{ map.buttonText }}</md-button>
        <md-input-container>
            <label>Div Adjustent</label>
            <input ng-model="map.divAdjustment">
        </md-input-container>
        <md-button ng-click="map.adjustDiv();" > Adjust Div Height </md-button>
        <p></p>
        <p>For testing - buttonEnabled value: <span ng-bind="map.buttonDisabled"></span></p>
        <p>{{ map.latitude }}</p>
        <p>{{ map.longitude }}</p>
        <p>{{ map.message }}</p>
        <p></p>
        <md-button ng-click="map.showMapDialog();">make map full screen</md-button>
        <!-- <div id="map" ng-show="map.locationUpdated"> -->
        <div id="map" ng-show="true"></div>
    </md-content>
</div>
```

map.controller.js

```
    console.log("map.controller.js file loaded");

angular.module('snApp')
.controller("MapController", ['$scope', MapController]);

function MapController($scope) {
    // Variables
    var vm = this;
    vm.latitude = 0;
    vm.longitude = 0;
    vm.locationUpdated = false;
    vm.buttonTextDefault = "Get Location";
    vm.buttonText = vm.buttonTextDefault;
    vm.buttonDisabled = false;

    vm.divAdjustment = 0;
    vm.message = "Map will display after getting Geolocation";

    // Method Declarations
    vm.getLocation = getLocation;
    vm.setMapToDiv = setMapToDiv;
    vm.showMapDialog = showMapDialog;
    // vm.adjustDiv = adjustDiv;

    // Gets the Current Geolocation for user
    function getLocation() {
        vm.buttonDisabled = true;
        vm.buttonText = "Working...";
        var options = { maximumAge: 0, timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: true };
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getLocationSuccess,getLocationError,options);
        vm.buttonDisabled = false;
    }

    function getLocationSuccess(position) {
        console.log("found geolocation");
        vm.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        vm.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        vm.buttonText = vm.buttonTextDefault;
        googleMaps.positionMapToCoords(vm.latitude, vm.longitude);
        vm.locationUpdated = true;
        $scope.$apply();
    }

    function getLocationError(error) {
        console.log("Error finding geolocation");
        alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
                'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
        vm.buttonText = vm.buttonTextDefault;
        $scope.$apply();
    }

    function setMapToDiv() {
        googleMaps.setMapToDiv();
    }

    function showMapDialog() {
        googleMaps.showMapDialog();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post some of your HTML? It looks like the Statusbar Plugin is doing its job, but the HTML in your WebView is off a bit.

Comment: @johnborges, sorry for the late reply, I added more HTML.  Something to note.  there is definitely an issue with the interaction between the google maps plug in and the status bar plug in.  It initiate the status bar plugin before the maps plugin, the status bar problem goes away.  but then the google map is off in its div.  As a solution I am setting StatusBar.overlaysWebView( true ); which causes the bar to go away and then the content goes under the bar, but I am just now detecting if IOS, where then I add an extra div for spacing.  I don't think i should have to do all that, but its a fix.

Comment: If there is nothing we can find as a solid solution.  I will just post my fix as the solution next week sometime.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone bumps into this, having the same issues.  I basically found a solution that was more of a workaround rather than a direct answer, but might be helpful.  I decided to use the plugin still for coloring the text properly, but the rest I am managing manually.

```
    StatusBar.overlaysWebView(true);
    StatusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#1D1D1D');
    StatusBar.styleLightContent();
```

Then some CSS

```
#statusBar {
    background-color:#1D1D1D;
    width:100%;
    min-width:100%;
    overflow: auto;
    min-height:20px;
    height:20px;
}
```

I have this div as a part of my menu bar.  The menu bar is its own angular component.  In the controller, i have a method that checks for the OS version. thanks to this post: [Detecting iOS / Android Operating system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21741841/detecting-ios-android-operating-system)

```
snApp.controller('menuBarController', ['$mdSidenav', '$window', '$googleMapsService', MenuBarController]);


function MenuBarController($mdSidenav, $window, $googleMapsService) {
    var vm = this;
    var leftMenuId = 'left';
    vm.isIosValue = false;

    vm.$onInit = function() {
        vm.isIosValue = vm.checkForIos();
    }

    vm.operatingSystem = null;
    vm.toggleLeftMenu = toggleLeftMenu;
    vm.getMobileOperatingSystem = getMobileOperatingSystem;
    vm.checkForIos = checkForIos;
    vm.isIos = isIos;

    vm.googleMaps = $googleMapsService;

    function toggleLeftMenu() {
        mapDivManagement();
        $mdSidenav(leftMenuId).onClose(mapDivManagement).toggle();
    }

    function mapDivManagement() {
        if(vm.googleMaps.checkMap() && $window.location.hash == "#/map")
        {
            if($mdSidenav(leftMenuId).isOpen()) {
                console.log("vm.googleMaps.revealMap(true);");
                vm.googleMaps.revealMap(true);
            }
            else {
                console.log("vm.googleMaps.revealMap(false);");
                vm.googleMaps.revealMap(false);
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * Determine the mobile operating system.
     * This function sets global variable to one of 'iOS', 'Android', 'Windows Phone', or 'unknown'.
     *
     * @returns {String}
     *
     * Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21741841/detecting-ios-android-operating-system
     */
    function getMobileOperatingSystem() {
        var userAgent = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;
        //debugger;
          // Windows Phone must come first because its UA also contains "Android"
        if (/windows phone/i.test(userAgent)) {
            // return "Windows Phone";
            vm.operatingSystem =  "Windows Phone";
        }
        else if (/android/i.test(userAgent)) {
            // return "Android";
            vm.operatingSystem =  "Android";
        }
        // iOS detection from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9039885/177710
        else if (/iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(userAgent) && !window.MSStream) {
            // return "iOS";
            vm.operatingSystem =  "iOS";
        }
        else {
            vm.operatingSystem =  "unknown";
        }
            // return "unknown";
    }

    function checkForIos() {
        vm.getMobileOperatingSystem();
        //vm.operatingSystem = $window.operatingSystem;
        if(vm.operatingSystem == 'iOS') {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    function isIos() {
        return vm.isIosValue;
    }
}
```

Finally, in my menubar.html file, I have this div:

```
    <!-- Status Bar -->
<div ng-show="menuBarController.isIos()" id="statusBar"></div>
```

which will show or hide the div based on the OS.

Not sure how this will all work in a call, but it gets you pretty far otherwise.