# how to first launch my website popup

Tags: web

I have a problem where I want to make my website when you first accessed through a mobile phone message to download the app or website.

What is needed? Can anyone help me solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript for example: 
You can set a cookie.

```
<script>
var tehDiv = document.getElemenbyId('adiv');
if (localStorage.getItem('firstTime'){
theDiv.innerHTML='';
}else{
localStorage.setItem('firstTime', 'no');
theDiv.innerHTML='The html that shows download app buttons';
}
</script>

<body>

blablablabla
<div id="adiv">Here will be placed download buttons or not</div>
```

If need to know if is a mobile there are many scripts to that. For example this one: [Detecting iOS / Android Operating system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21741841/detecting-ios-android-operating-system)