# Android video plays on iOS device but not on Android device

Tags: android, ios, iphone, video, ionic2

I have a strange situation where:

- Android recorded video plays on an iPhone but not on an Android device
- iPhone recorded videos play on both iPhones and Android devices

The HTML I use is:

```
          <video controls="controls">
            <source type="video/quicktime" [src]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(step.attachment)">
            <source type="video/mp4" [src]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(step.attachment)">
          </video>
```

The `step.attachment` is a base64 file.

My App is built with ionic 2

Comment: Are you playing streaming video or playing after downloading?

Comment: Can you please provide audio and video encoding you used to record video ?

Comment: The video is a base64 encoded file in memory

Comment: Why is Quicktime used on a HTML5 video tag??? Quicktime (`.mov`) is made by Apple so it will work on iOS browser (but not guaranteed for other systems). **(1)** Try removing `<source type="video/quicktime"...etc` when testing on Android? **(2)** Try NOT using Base64 (in case Android browser's video decoder expects real MP4 bytes within a video tag)?

Comment: The files have to base64 because of the way they are stored. The Android phone has no problem playing the base64 video recorded on an iPhone. It is only the video recorded on an Android phone which can't be played on an Android phone (but can be played on an iPhone!). Two source tags are used, one quicktime and one mp4, to cater for both iPhone and Android.

Comment: Try to use 3GP instead of MP4 format

Comment: It is an mp4 file

Comment: Can you try to reverse the order of the source tags and see if the behavior on Android and iOS changes? It might be that Android just tries to use the codec from the first source entry - which is ok for QuickTime videos created on iOS, but not for videos created on Android. If the behavior "reverses" too, the solution would be to have the type declaration dependent on the encoded video somehow.

Comment: I have removed the quicktime source tag to see if that made a difference on Android and it doesn't

Comment: there sometimes happen the issue of streams normally video is stream #0 and audio stream #1 and if these swaps android will behave weird , anyway is it possible to host the page and file online ? then checking the issue will be easier....

Comment: How can I specify the stream?

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment but I don't have enough rep to comment.

Perhaps explicitly determine the [OS of the phone first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21741841/detecting-ios-android-operating-system) and only define the video source for that OS.

For instance, the following algorithm:

if OS == Android,
  video controls source type="video/mp4"

else if OS == iOS,
   video controls source type="video/quicktime"

Although I don't see why what you have should not work, hopefully you lose nothing trying this.

Comment: I have removed the quicktime source tag to see if that made a difference on Android and it doesn't