# JavaScript detect in application usage

Tags: javascript, android, ios

I need to detect a usage from Android `WebView` or iOS `UIWebView` or any in app usage.

Checking the user agent for mobile like [detecting-ios-android-operating-system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21741841/detecting-ios-android-operating-system) or any mobile like -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (/Mobi/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
        // mobile!
    }
});
```

Is not enough beacuse I want to disable some button and use the application navigation buttons but if the user is on mobile browser I want to keep the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to detect mobile devices devices:

```
// detect browser
    var android = navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) != null;    // Check if using Android
    var iPad = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null;          // Check if using an iPad
    var iPhone = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) != null;      // Check if using an iPhone
```

Detecting Webviews inside apps is much harder as those are not really distinguished from normal browser views.

From Google Dev docs you can check for `Version/_X.X_`:

> If you’re attempting to differentiate between the WebView and Chrome
>   for Android, you should look for the presence of the Version/*X.X*
>   string in the WebView user-agent string. Don’t rely on the specific
>   Chrome version number (for example, 30.0.0.0) as the version numbers
>   changes with each release.

https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/user-agent#webview_user_agent

And then this posts answer gives good info on detecting for iOS

[detect ipad/iphone webview via javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460205/detect-ipad-iphone-webview-via-javascript)

Something like this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10170885/5234751

```
var is_uiwebview = /(iPhone|iPod|iPad).*AppleWebKit(?!.*Safari)/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
var is_safari_or_uiwebview = /(iPhone|iPod|iPad).*AppleWebKit/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
```