# Is it possible to delay the PWA banner "add to home screen" on android devices?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

My app have some intro pages I want the user see before android shows the banner "Add to home screen", is it possible? 
or another solution maybe hide it for a while...

Thank you very much, any help very appreciated.

Comment: have a look at `setTimeout?`

Comment: Is this a website, or an actual mobile app?

Answer (score 0):

The browser has a global var named navigator.userAgent. It contains a string that you can do an indexOf against to see if the app is running on android, like so:

```
//'True' if "Android" is in the user agent
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Android') != -1)
    console.log('running on android')
```

[Detecting iOS / Android Operating system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21741841/detecting-ios-android-operating-system)