# js script query to target only iOS devices

Tags: html, reactjs, react-native

how can i create a website that only ios user can visit in other words if you're on windows and andriod the website will be block you saying this website is only for ios please download this on andriod instead

also is there's anyway to make a native app on ios for free?

Comment: Check this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21741841/detecting-ios-android-operating-system

Answer (score 0):

In a website you can easily use this function to understand the operating system

```
function getOperatingSystem(window) {
  let operatingSystem = 'Not known';
  if (window.navigator.appVersion.indexOf('Win') !== -1) { operatingSystem = 'Windows OS'; }
  if (window.navigator.appVersion.indexOf('Mac') !== -1) { operatingSystem = 'MacOS'; }
  if (window.navigator.appVersion.indexOf('X11') !== -1) { operatingSystem = 'UNIX OS'; }
  if (window.navigator.appVersion.indexOf('Linux') !== -1) { operatingSystem = 'Linux OS'; }

  return operatingSystem;
}
```

With react native you can develop iOS app for free, but be aware that to publish an app in the Apple store you would need an iOS developer account and it will cost around 100$ or more.

see https://developer.apple.com/programs/enroll/