# Detecting Android Menu Icons based on Android Version

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-mobile, web-applications, icons

I'm currently adding a popup (Add To Home Screen Feature) to an existing mobile web app using jQuery mobile. I would like to place the exact same icon the user has on their phone (based on Android version) inside the popup instructions rather than show 6 different icons the user may have.

Is there any specific jquery/javascript doing this or can anyone provide or direct me to an icon set (specifically just the menu icon) with android version numbers that I can pull from to create some logic to determine exactly the menu icon they need (based on version) to press to bookmark the site? I can't find this anywhere.

Edit:
Looking specifically for hardware specific menu icons for Android devices. They use many different kinds and would like to know if I can detect the device hardware being used and use the appropriate icon? Is this even possible?

Comment: There is no "menu" icon in Android. What are you considering a "menu" icon? You may wish to upload a screenshot somewhere and link to it from your question.

Comment: An example of a menu icon I'm referring too can be seen here [link](http://www.udemo.ca/save_icon_android.jpg)

Comment: That icon is not part of the Android SDK.

Comment: Ok. So these icons must be hardware specific.

Comment: This should not be possible from a Web server. If this were a hybrid app, then there may be hooks for that, or you could add one via a plugin mechanism. But there are a variety of Web browsers for Android, and there is no guarantee that the `User-Agent` headers will uniquely identify a device model. In fact, any browsers that *do* include that information are IMHO leaking too much information from a privacy/security front. Moreover, there are thousands upon thousands of Android device models, and I am not aware of any database of hardware-specific icons for them.

Comment: makes perfect sense. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can figure out the android version using this code [from another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184573/pick-up-the-android-version-in-the-browser-by-javascript).

There used to be no standard for android menu buttons.  Hardware manufacturers tended to make the menu icon whatever they wanted. I would heavily suggest using the modern, unified icon with three dots like [this one from the android developers site](https://developer.android.com/design/media/iconography_actionbar_colors.png).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I may have to go with the latest or not show a menu icon at all and just describe what to do to bookmark.