# how can we use USER-AGENT string to differentiate between 1.Laptop/Desktop 2.IOS 3. Android 4.Other handsets (BB, Nokia, MS Mobile)

Tags: android, ios, c, user-agent

I want specific keys so that i can make a distinction between the devices using user-agent string.
1.       Laptop/Desktop
2.       IOS
3.       Android
4.       Other handsets (BB, Nokia, MS Mobile)

Comment: 1) Laptop/Desktop will not have mobile in their UA

Comment: ok thanks for that, what about the other mobile devices

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12606245/detect-if-browser-is-running-on-an-android-or-ios-device

Answer (score 0):

You can detect mobile devices using regular expressions on the User-Agent:

90% of the mobile devices can be detected using

```
/Mobile|Android|BlackBerry/
```

If you want to detect around 98% of mobile devices you can use this one:

```
/Mobile|iP(hone|od|ad)|Android|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Kindle|NetFront|Silk-Accelerated|(hpw|web)OS|Fennec|Minimo|Opera M(obi|ini)|Blazer|Dolfin|Dolphin|Skyfire|Zune/
```

You can use a subset of the last regex to target specific ones.

About detecting between desktop and laptop it is just NOT possible using user-agent. You need additional information that it is not in the UA such as macaddr or model name.