# Javascript To know if device IOS or android to show div

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, ios

hi all i am looking for simple javascript just to determination if the user use IOS or ANDROID so if user use IOS i will show the div say: download app from Apple store if Android i will say download app from play store.
how i can know the type of the device ? 
and show the div depend on that?
also i need to test it where i can test this script if work well as a IOS and Android environment or not ? 
is it easy to do that ?
i am using HTMl and Javascript for this
the idea here i will show div for first time only when the user visit the site to download the app
i did it but am looking to determination the device type if its IOS or Android

Comment: Did you even try to find an answer yourself?

Comment: var isMobile = {
    Android: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) ? true : false;
    },
    BlackBerry: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i) ? true : false;
    },
    iOS: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i) ? true : false;
    },
    Windows: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i) ? true : false;
    },
    any: function() {
        return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Windows());
    }
};

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 var isMobile = {
    Android: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
    },
    BlackBerry: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
    },
    iOS: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
    },
    Opera: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
    },
    Windows: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
    },
    any: function() {
        return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());
    }

};



if (isMobile.Android()) {
     //android code.
}
else if(isMobile.iOS())
{
     //ios code.
}
```

Comment: <span class="comment-copy">possible duplicate of <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12606245/detect-if-browser-is-running-on-an-android-or-ios-device">Detect if browser is running on an Android or iOS device</a></span>

Comment: can i add the div in th if statment ?

Comment: @user3469218:yes you can.

Comment: Add a source when you copy code.