# how to display an element depending on Operating System?

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, svg

I am using Angular and I am doing a Mobile App where I am including a spinner which is a loader, is an SVG, the thing here: that SVG is not been displayed on some Android versions, in iPhone, works great, but not in Android, so what I want to do: detect the OS and depending on that display the SVG or just an image that I have in my project.

this is the SVG

```
<div>{{spinnerTitle}}</div>
<svg class="spinner" width="60px" height="80px"
     viewBox="0 0 66 66" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <circle class="path" fill="none"
            stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round"
            cx="33" cy="33" r="30">
    </circle>
</svg>
```

so what do you recommend ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should follow the following steps:

1. Check the value of `navigator.userAgent` with each version where you do not want to display the svg
2. Make a list of key texts present in the values to be excluded (a black list)
3. If `navigator.userAgent` does not correspond to any pattern in the blacklist, then show the svg
4. Test on as many devices as possible

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12606245/detect-if-browser-is-running-on-an-android-or-ios-device) to get some more information.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [platform.js](https://github.com/bestiejs/platform.js/), it does good work detecting various client platform data, saves you do that manually yourself :).