# Web Page that redirects Android or iOS to determined pages

Tags: javascript, android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I created a QR Code that links to my Facebook page (not my profile, a fan page) and its an internal link that opens the Facebook app when scanned, *fb://profile/114726115215664* , but this only works for iOS. On Android i am given an error but the Facebook app opens saying that the page does not exist.

I have evaluated a solution: the new QR Code will link to a web page that has code that will determine the device and redirect for iOS (or safari) to the FB app and Android (or Android Chrome) to the browser version of Facebook. I have minimal knowledge of html or javascript and cant figure out the right code for this. Hopefully someone here has the answer :)

Comment: See if [this answer can](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12606298/3307872) help you. Be sure to read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12606293/3307872) also, as it explains why detecting only the OS is not waterproof.

Comment: on the Android forum: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/60098/open-facebook-links-with-facebook-app