# Android Browser doesn't load my website in Android version 4.0.4

Tags: javascript, android, phonegap-plugins, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I've found some issues somehow related to mine here in SO but none of them helped me so far, so i'll try to explain the best i can.

When I open my website in Android Browser in the Android 4.0.4 version, it doesn't load any page of the website, it only appears a white page and do nothing.
I've tried with Google Chrome and Firefox and others browsers and it worked. I've tested in many devices with this version and it happens the same thing too, so it wasn't the device.

The website is this https://www.findhit.com

I've tried to open other websites similar that the website that i'm trying to open in this specific version of the browser, and it worked normally, so i have the conclusion that it's my website problem with this browser version.

I thought that maybe this Android Browser version doesn't have some compatibility with some native javascript functions that i'm using and because of that it doesn't load what it needs to start the app, because i've debugged it, and some variables wasn't like they have to be to start the app.
I've noticed that the events sometimes doesn't fire but i didn't really understand why, maybe it was because it didn't load some variables.

And i'm using phonegap inappbrowser to load my website in the mobile app and inappbrowser it's using the Android Browser, so i can't make it work there too because of that.

So if anyone have some clue what it can be or have some more information about compatibility of this browser with native javascript functions or events, i'll be really glad for any help.

Sorry if i'm being too ambiguous, but i don't know what more can i do about this, im in a long time trying to get a solution to this and i really have to make this work in this specific version of Android Browser.

Really thanks in advance.

Comment: Code examples or a link to the site would help to see what the issue could be.

Comment: Sorry i forget to put the link to the website. The code examples i don't have clue what to put here sorry.

Comment: I can only assume it's to do with the CSS/jQuery combination, more likely the jQuery as you stated it's working in Chrome and Firefox. Something similar to [this question's answer] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12606245/detect-if-browser-is-running-on-an-android-or-ios-device) may solve your problem, redirect if Android browser and show a simple page.

Comment: I don't think that is the solution that i'm looking for, but thanks anyway for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally found the solution for this. The problem it was that version of Android wasn't loading the `window.document` when the page was loaded. ( Still don't know why ) So the solution was, put the document in the `window.prototype.document` and the browser looks in the `window.document` if it doesn't find there looks in the prototype.
I don't know if it was the time of loading that the window doesn't had the document there yet and when it looks in the prototype had already loaded, im still trying to discover what was really going on there, but this solution fixed my problem though.