# Detect if Chrome is on Android, iOS, or Desktop Chrome?

Tags: javascript

How can I use Java Script to detect if Chrome is on Android, iOS or Desktop.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21757105/javascript-how-to-check-user-agent-for-mobile-tablet ?

Comment: check out this  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12606245/detect-if-browser-is-running-on-an-android-or-ios-device

Comment: and this topic may help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031412/detect-android-phone-via-javascript-jquery