# Check Mobile type right ? Javascript show a div ONCE depending on mobile type

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, dom-events

All what I need to know if I checking the mobile type in right way?
Is there  other way to check the mobile type?

See my way below in the code. 
How  can I try it using any tool?

Does anyone know the right way to check the mobile type if IOS OR ANDROID?
Below is my code:

```
<head>
    <style>
            #IOS_USERS {
                display: block;
                display:none;
            }

            #ANDROID_USERS {
                display: block;
                display:none;
            }

    </style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
//check mobile type
var isMobile = {
    Android: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
    },
    BlackBerry: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
    },
    iOS: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i);
    },
    Opera: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
    },
    Windows: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
    },
    any: function() {
        return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());
    }

};

            function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
                var d = new Date();
                d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
                var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
                document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
            }


            function getCookie(cname) {
                var name = cname + "=";
                var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
                for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
                    var c = ca[i].trim();
                    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
                }
                return "";
            }

            function MarkVisited() {
                setCookie("visited", "visited", 10)
            }

            function ClearCookie(cname) {
                setCookie(cname, "", 1)
            }



            $(document).ready(function() {

                 if (getCookie('visited') == "" && isMobile.iOS()) {
                    $('#ANDROID_USERS').hide();
                    $('#IOS_USERS').show();
                }
                else if (getCookie('visited') == "" && isMobile.Android()) {
                    $('#ANDROID_USERS').show();
                    $('#IOS_USERS').hide();
                }
                MarkVisited();
            });
</script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="IOS_USERS">
         IOS 
        </div>
        <div id="ANDROID_USERS">
         ANDROID 
        </div>
        <button id="ClearCookie" onClick="ClearCookie('visited')">Clear Cookie</button>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-handheld-device-in-jquery and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031412/detect-android-phone-via-javascript-jquery

Comment: i dont get it how i can apply it in my code ?

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
window.mobilecheck = function() {
var check = false;
(function(a){if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4)))check = true})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);
return check; }
```

Or :

```
function detectmob() { 
 if( navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)
 ){
    return true;
  }
 else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Or You can try detect width /height mobile:
I.

```
function detectmob() {
   if(window.innerWidth <= 800 && window.innerHeight <= 600) {
     return true;
   } else {
     return false;
   }
}
```

II.

```
if ($(window).width() <600){}
```

Or Css :

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) and (min-width:300px) {}
```

etc.

Comment: its needed to change /Android/i to android user agent ?

Comment: I don't fink so.
Try:
   'function detectmob() { 
      if( navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i){
        "Do something"
      }
   }'