# How to display DIV only in android device?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How to display DIV only in android device ?

i want to add button that if you click it go in whatsapp app. bot only in android devices

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect Android phone via Javascript / jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031412/detect-android-phone-via-javascript-jquery)

Comment: Where is your code?  What have you tried?  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Using `navigator.userAgent` you are able to check operating system of agent who opens your page. For example try this:

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1;
if(isAndroid) {
  // SHOW YOUR DIV
}
```

Comment: Answer copied from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031412/detect-android-phone-via-javascript-jquery