# Detecting Android (not chrome) with javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

I've found plenty of answers on this.  The one I'm trying now is:

```
 /(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent)
```

But in Chrome on Windows I get `true`.  I'm trying to detect when my user is on an Android device (to point them to the Play Store listing).  Is there any reliable way to achieve this?

Comment: maybe this one can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031412/detect-android-phone-via-javascript-jquery

Comment: @ad_on_is that's the same thing

Comment: hmmm... can you check www.whatismybrowser.com with Chrome on Windows? Maybe you have a plugin or developer-tools setting that simulates android?

Answer (score 2):

I just tried this answer, and the code worked for me: [Detect Android phone via Javascript / jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031412/detect-android-phone-via-javascript-jquery)

Here is their code:

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1; //&& ua.indexOf("mobile");
if(isAndroid) {
  // Do something!
  // Redirect to Android-site?
  window.location = 'http://android.davidwalsh.name';
}
```

I also made a CodePen [here](http://codepen.io/josephbeard/pen/qrLwVa) where you can test it out.

I tested my CodePen on Chrome for Windows, Chrome for Mac, and Chrome for Android, and it worked correctly for all.