# How can i know and check { if user open my app from real android mobile not browser inspect (mobile mood) }?

Tags: php, android

I'm using PHP development in my android App like web-view
but I have a Trouble.

now I want to enable my web app (web-view) on real mobile-only, And I want to disable my website when any user open my web app URL from laptop or desktop/ any OS Like ( Windows / Mac / Linux ), Especially when any user use browser inspect (mobile mood),

My Ask >> How can I know and check (if the user opens my app from real android mobile, not browser inspect (mobile mood))?

How can I know that with PHP?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031412/detect-android-phone-via-javascript-jquery

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117555/simplest-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device

Comment: var is_mobile = /mobile/i.test (navigator.userAgent);
and 
$ua = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
not working when i use browser inspect (mobile mood)